# Why Sonarqube is shhowing this Warning S4056: "Use the overload that takes a 'CultureInfo' or 'IFormatProvider' parameter"

Tags: c#, .net, string, unit-testing, sonarqube

I'm having this warning S4056: Use the overload that takes a 'CultureInfo' or 'IFormatProvider' parameter when I do the assert in this line of code:

`Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, statusCode);`

both parameters are integers and I can't overload this method to accept the FormarProvider that is required to solve this warning, what is the best way to solve this warning?

[Sonarqube warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX3yw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no overload of `AreEqual` method for type of `int`, so the parameters are being parsed to `String`. That's why is requires cultural parameter. Why not using that:

```
Assert.IsTrue(((int)HttpStatusCode.OK) == statusCode);
```

Comment: This solution hides important information. Original code + CultureInfo produces error with a detailed information, like `200 != 203`. Your proposal shows `true` or `false`. You will have to debug the test to get information which status code has been returned.